# Redirect to different domains based on languages (Joomla)

Tags: redirect, joomla, dns

I have a website (joomla) with 2 different languages (spanish and english) managed with Falang.

The idea is to redirect:

-Spanish to mysite.es

-English to mysite.com

I have been using the plugin Language Domains by Yireo but it´s incompatible with Falang and he seems not interested in fix that bug.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not actually a programming question. You could have better luck asking it at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This joomla extension is a good solution: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtual-domains

Answer (score 0):

now it seams to work with Falang 2.5.0 and Yireo LanguageDomains.
Be sure that you have the correct plugin order - first should be languagedomains plugin, then I have the Joomla SEF and after this comes the falang database driver.

Only the falang modul has problems with the item association - to get it work I had to add one exclamation mark in the languagedomains.php, row 381

Hope this help someone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12437659)

Comment: But the question was how to redirect every language to an own domain in Joomla - this is the answer: Falang together with the plugin languagedomains from yireo.

Comment: And I answered the solution to the bug, that languagedomains has to work well together with falang. I thought if someone else has the same question (like me before I fixed the bug) that this answer helps him.